# Reduce battery drain using Voip and Location services Enabled

Tags: ios, ios10, voip, battery, sinch

We have implemented a chat based application based on mqtt.But recently we implemented calling feature by enabling voip and using Sinch frame work. After  enabling voip battery consumption in settings showing as 85% - 90%.How to improve battery life.

Comment: Apple has published a [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you are enable any Background modes from capability, it will run your app in the background mode that consumes a lot of battery. If any app runs in background it will consume more battery, so its better to customize your app while using background mode.